# Trying to Set State and Function in Next/React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to set a state and run a function in react but these components are in separate files, so I have my main app and 2 components (header and sidebar) in my components folder. In the header component, I have a hamburger menu that has an `onclick` event to it and once it's clicked I want the sidebar to open or close (toggle it).

How would I go about doing this without putting the header and sidebar into one component file? I do not want the sidebar on 1 or 2 pages but I will require the header for those 1 or 2 pages.

Here are my current files

App.js

```
import Drawer from "@/components/Drawer/Drawer";
import Header from "@/components/Header/Header";
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar/Sidebar";

import Head from "next/head";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Site Title</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <Drawer />
            <Header />
            <Sidebar />
        </>
    );
}
```

Header.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import Logo from "assets/logo.png";
import Avatar from "assets/avatar.png";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/NotificationsNoneOutlined";
import AppsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AppsOutlined";

function Header() {
    return (
        <header className="h-[60px] w-full bg-primary-color border-b border-hr-color fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-between px-4 z-[2]">
            <div className="left flex items-center">
                <div
                    className="menuicon hover:rounded-full hover:bg-[#e5e5e5] p-2 cursor-pointer group"
                    id="sidebar__btn"
                    onClick={toggleSidebar}
                >
                    <MenuIcon className="text-main-color group-hover:text-black" />
                </div>
                <Link className="flex items-center" href="/">
                    <Image
                        src={Logo}
                        loading="eager"
                        priority={true}
                        alt="My Logo"
                        className="rounded-full w-[56px]"
                    />
                    <span className="w-auto inline-flex uppercase font-roboto text-2xl font-medium">
                        site name
                    </span>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="center relative min-w-fit flex items-center">
                <div className="search__input w-full flex items-center relative">
                    <input
                        className="min-w-[800px] w-full outline-0 border border-search-border bg-search-input text-search-color text-base p-[10px] rounded-tl-md rounded-bl-md"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search..."
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="search__btn bg-[#ffffff14] border border-search-border w-[50px] h-[46px] cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-center border-l-0 rounded-tr-md rounded-br-md">
                    <SearchIcon />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="right flex items-center space-x-6">
                <div className="hover:rounded-full hover:bg-[#e5e5e5] p-2 cursor-pointer group">
                    <AppsOutlinedIcon className="text-3xl text-main-color group-hover:text-black" />
                </div>
                <div className="hover:rounded-full hover:bg-[#e5e5e5] p-2 cursor-pointer group">
                    <NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon className="text-3xl text-main-color group-hover:text-black" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Image
                        src={Avatar}
                        alt="Avatar"
                        className="flex w-[43px] cursor-pointer"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Sidebar.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import SidebarRow from "./SidebarRow";
import HomeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HomeOutlined";
import RocketOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/RocketOutlined";
import SimCardDownloadOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SimCardDownloadOutlined";
import ImageOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ImageOutlined";

function Sidebar({ onClick }) {
    const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
    function toggleSidebar() {
        console.log("now open");
        // isSidebarOpen === true ? setIsSidebarOpen(false) : setIsSidebarOpen(true);
    }
    return (
        <div
            className={`sidebar bg-primary-color fixed w-[230px] top-0 bottom-0 left-0 pt-[75px] transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out ${
                isSidebarOpen == true
                    ? "translate-x-0"
                    : "translate-x-[-100%] left-[-100%]"
            }`}
        >
            <SidebarRow Icon={HomeOutlinedIcon} title="home" />
            <SidebarRow Icon={RocketOutlinedIcon} title="products" />
            <SidebarRow Icon={SimCardDownloadOutlinedIcon} title="downloads" />
            <SidebarRow Icon={ImageOutlinedIcon} title="gallery" />
            <hr className="mt-5 border-hr-color" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state needs to be in your App component the way you have it now.  The hamburger menu click in header will call a props.onToggleHeader type function that you pass in and set the state in App.js.   Then you have a property you pass into sidebar with if its open or not.

So to summarize (and this is pseudo code but you seem to have a handle on the semantics):

App.js:

```html
const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false);

<Header onToggleSidebar={() => setIsSidebarOpen(!isSidebarOpen)}  />
<Sidebar isOpen={isSidebarOpen} />
```

Comment: thank you very much, i didnt think about sending props through the components in the app the way you suggested. Trouble i have now is the way it opens and closes the sidebar. It opens nice and slow but flys off when closing, Here is the code i have for that
`className={`sidebar bg-primary-color fixed w-[230px] top-0 bottom-0 left-0 pt-[75px] transition duration-700 ease-in-out ${ isOpen == true ? "translate-x-0" : "translate-x-[-100%] left-[-100%]" }`}`

Comment: @puggsy21 sorry, css isnt my wheelhouse :) . Glad the suggestion helped you though, you were most the way there :)

Comment: yeh got it all working as intended just got to look at the transition durations and stuff, but without your suggestion i would still be scratching my head (most likely be bald by now) i will keep looking at it thou, again thank you